# How to disable tip when hover on text in ace editor

Tags: hover, tooltip, ace-editor

[image]

If only mouse hover on some text, an tip with write background will jump.
Does anyone know how to prevent this happen?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: where do you see this tooltip? it is not present on https://ace.c9.io

Comment: i used Ace 1.2.2 version. Sorry, i don't know why this happen?

Comment: could you create a demo, or give url of the site where this issue can be reproduced?

Comment: You should post the code as code, not as an image. I really cannot understand why so many people posts screenshots of their code, on a **programming** **Q&A** site, not the code itself :)